# endless loop / StackOverflowError when using Apache MyFaces 2.0

Tags: tomcat, jsf, jsf-2, myfaces

I just like to give JSF 2.0 (MyFaces 2.0) a try using Tomcat 6.0.
I am completely new to JSF. I just put a static xhtml as `test.jsf` in the application root. When request the URL, a `StackOverflowError` will always be thrown:

```
 java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest$AttributeNamesEnumerator.<init>(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:904)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.getAttributeNames(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:243)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest$AttributeNamesEnumerator.<init>(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:905)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.getAttributeNames(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:243)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest$AttributeNamesEnumerator.<init>(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:905)
```

(repeated many times, but then:)

```
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest$AttributeNamesEnumerator.<init>(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:905)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.getAttributeNames(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:243)
 at org.apache.myfaces.context.servlet.RequestMap.getAttributeNames(RequestMap.java:66)
 at org.apache.myfaces.util.AbstractAttributeMap.isEmpty(AbstractAttributeMap.java:100)
 at org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.ErrorPageWriter._writeVariables(ErrorPageWriter.java:558)
 at org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.ErrorPageWriter._writeVariables(ErrorPageWriter.java:538)
 at org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.ErrorPageWriter.debugHtml(ErrorPageWriter.java:259)
 at org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.ErrorPageWriter.debugHtml(ErrorPageWriter.java:221)
 at org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.ErrorPageWriter.handleThrowable(ErrorPageWriter.java:384)
 at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:102)
 at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:189)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:436)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:374)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:302)
 at org.apache.myfaces.context.servlet.ServletExternalContextImpl.dispatch(ServletExternalContextImpl.java:439)
 at org.apache.myfaces.view.jsp.JspViewDeclarationLanguage.buildView(JspViewDeclarationLanguage.java:115)
 at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:103)
 at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:207)
 at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:191)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:436)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:374)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:302)
 at org.apache.myfaces.context.servlet.ServletExternalContextImpl.dispatch(ServletExternalContextImpl.java:439)
 at org.apache.myfaces.view.jsp.JspViewDeclarationLanguage.buildView(JspViewDeclarationLanguage.java:115)
 at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:103)
 at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:207)
 at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:191)
```

(also repeated many times...)

What did I made wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `StackOverflowError` during a HTTP servlet request indicates an infinite recursion in the servlet/filter mappings. How is your `FacesServlet` mapped? It should be mapped to listen on an `url-pattern` of `*.jsf` and thus **not** `*.xhtml` (which is a common mistake by starters). It will otherwise call itself recursively. The *actual* files should be named `*.xhtml`. You just call it as `*.jsf` in the URL. Please consult/refer the JSF 2.0 [books](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071625097)/[tutorials](http://www.coreservlets.com/JSF-Tutorial/jsf2/)/[documentation](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/tutorial/doc/bnaph.html) closely how to configure/use JSF properly.

Comment: thank you, using .xhtml instead of .jsf worked. Why does it call recursivly when its suffixed by .jsf btw?

Comment: Because the *actual* filename would then match the `URL-pattern`. The `FacesServlet` namely internally forwards the request to the actual file which in turn may invoke another servlets/filters listening on the URL in question. In this particular case, the `FacesServlet` itself will be invoked again .. infinite loop!